# Does $ f([0,1])$ must always contain an irrational number?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

if $f(x)$ is a one to one function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ then
how to prove that $ f([0,1])$ must contain an irrational number. Also prove that $f(x)$ need not contain rational number.

I really don't know how to approach such questions.

Comment: Cardinality...${}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is uncountable, and so because $f$ is injective, so will $f([0,1])$.  If $f([0,1])$ did not contain an irrational number, then it would lie in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so be countable.  But that would give us a contradiction.

Because $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$, there is in fact a bijection from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

As an attempt at a constructive example for the second question,  define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \{\pi+x\}  & x \text{ is of the form } n\pi+q \text{  for } n \text{ non-negative integer and } q \text { rational} \\ x & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, though strictly speaking this is a bijection $[0,1) \to [0,1)\backslash \mathbb{Q}$.